# Custom XML-based Document in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation, core-foundation

I am trying to develop library for handling [XLIFF files](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html).
Looking at the `FoundationXML` and how it is implemented, it is using `CFXMLInterface` for parsing XML
Is there a way to use `CFXMLInterface` as it is used on [FoundationXML/XMLParser](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/tree/main/Sources/FoundationXML)  to build custom XML based document parser, without building the whole `CoreFoundation`?
In general I want to know if it is possible to reference `CFXMLInterface`.
Thank you.